# How to use data set by one fixture as parameter in another fixture in PyTest?

Tags: python, pytest

In `test_global_data()` I would like to do something (e.g. check the value) with all items received in `get_set_data()` as json array (`json_data`) so I need to use the `json_data` as parameter in `get_item` but it doesn't work.
The `json_data` looks like:
`[ {value: None, name: 'name1'}, {value: 2, name: 'name2'}, ... ]`

Is it possible to use global data set by one fixture as parameter in another fixture?

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture(scope='session')
def json_data(request, handle):
    json_data = get_json_data(handle) # get json data from remote data source
    request.config.cache.set('json_data', json_data)
    return json_data

@pytest.fixture(params = json_data, ids = [item['name'] for item in json_data, scope="session") # pass the json_data from get_set_data() as parameter
def get_item(request):
    yield request.param

def test_global_data(request, get_item):
    assert get_item['value'] is not None # this is just an example as it should be actually more complex operation
```

Comment: Why don't you just yield the data in the first fixture? Or if that is not wanted for some reason, you could just make the second fixture use the first one.

Comment: Yielding the `json_data` in the first fixture would give me entire array. I want to get item by item from that array using `get_item()`. For the second option: how can I do it so that calling `get_item` returns item by item from `json_data` in a nice way without looping?

Comment: Why not just `@pytest.fixture(params=get_json_data(),...`?

Comment: Maybe not the best example. I can't get around the fact that the `json_data` is produced in a fixture (it cannot be a function). And I need it as parameter in `get_item` fixture

Comment: The problem is that the parametrization (direct or via `pytest_generate_tests`) is done _before_ the fixtures are executed. Are you sure you cannot refactor the code so that the relevant part can be executed in a function somehow?

Comment: I tried, but I would need to call a fixture function inside a normal (non-test-case) function, which seems to be impossible.

Comment: The question is at what point do you really need a fixture in your case - do you need to use some of the standard pytest fixtures somewhere? Difficult to say without knowing the actual code...